# Passing JSON to a WCF web method

Tags: json, wcf

I have a web service where some clients are experiencing issues calling the app.

The issue relates to them passing in JSON, and specifying the Content-Type header as JSON, but the WCF service doesn't seem to accept that header, and either wants that header not to be set, or to be set to octet-stream.

The strange thing is, a separate web method works when the Content-Type header is set to application/json.

Here is the Attributes and declaration of the method I am having trouble with

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "events/{eventId}/devices/{deviceId}/setid?ac={ac}")]
    OperationResult SetId(string eventId, string deviceId, string ac, Stream data);
```

And this is the attributes and declaration of the method which works

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "activate?deviceId={deviceID}")]
OperationResult<ActivationResult> ActivateDevice(string deviceID, Stream data);
```

Now I know they are 2 different methods, but the activate method works if I provide the Content-Type header of application/json, but the SetId method does not.

In the actual implementation of each method, the stream parameters are converted to the corresponding JSON class. Any ideas why this is not working for both?

The exception message is 'Incoming message for operation 'SetId' contains an unrecognized http body format value 'Json'. The expected body format value is 'Raw'.

Comment: Try using `RequestFormat` and `ResponseFormat` attributes. e.g.: `[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "events/{eventId}/devices/{deviceId}/setid?ac={ac}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]`

Comment: Still experiencing the same issue @thisisbobbs

Comment: Which binding are you using? Please provide your web.config, or your channel setup code if you're configuring in code.